# Is there a way to disable all TouchEvents on children in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

To simplify the question:

I'm looking for something exactly like the typical mouseEnabled=false, mouseChildren=false that works for TouchEvents. Did anyone at Adobe think to implement that?

Comment: mouseEnabled should block touch events as well, I believe. Otherwise, why not just remove the eventlistener?

Comment: MouseEnabled doesn't block TouchEvents. The thing I'm building is a touch-enabled scrollpane that can take any arbitrary content. So there's no way to know what listeners are in that content, or what they're doing - and while the scrollpane is being dragged I want all touch events within it to be ignored (so you don't accidentally tap or drag something within the content once it's clear that you're trying to drag the pane). Also since those listeners are deeper on the display chain there is no way to intercept and stop their propagation from the scrollpane itself.

Comment: According to the [Documentation of MultitouchMode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/MultitouchInputMode.html#NONE) setting it to NONE interprets all touches as MouseEvents, so in theory, mouseEnabled would block them. Not sure if this will solve your issue, but maybe it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: Well... yes but setting it to NONE makes it so that no TouchEvents are dispatched at all. I want to be able to put touch enabled content inside this scrollpane (including multitouch) and have it work normally as long as the pane isn't in the process of scrolling. But I want to cancel all internal touches immediately once the pane thinks it's scrolling. This is the same kind of behavior that's native in stuff like the android radio button list. It seems like right now the only content you could put inside would have to be limited to mouse events (simulating touch_tap)...

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have some kind of logic that decides if the content is being scrolled. Set the mode to NONE then and mouseEnabled to false for the content, this will block all interaction with the content. And once you determine that the scrolling stops, reset the mode to the previous mode and reenable mouseEnable. I can't think of another way, this is the only possibility that I can think of.

Comment: I do - the logic is that once the scrolling is more than 4 pixels in either axis I want to disable the events within the masked child display object. But bear in mind that I don't want to disable the touch events controlling the scrollpane itself. Changing the MultitouchMode of the whole SWF would prevent the current gesture (on the scrollpane) from dispatching when it was finished. I could probably just use mouse events for the scrollpane; it seems like a hack but it might solve the problem.